# Turn endomorphisms into Applicative

Tags: haskell, coordinate-transformation, applicative, monoids

Say we have a `data Vector` with an obvious operation (so Vector is instance of Monoid)

```
(+):: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
```

Now, say we want some object to be movable by vector.
Say I know exactly the types which are considered movable, so *there is* some move function

```
move :: Vector -> Movable -> Movable
```

where `data Movable = Movable t1 | t2 | t3`

Or the class version

```
class Movable a where
  move :: Vector -> a -> a
```

with some instances of the form

```
instance Movable ti where
  move :: Vector -> ti -> ti
```

Personally, I prefer the class version.

Now, say we have a series of computations roughly equivalent to

```
move v1 . move v2 . move v3
```

Which in the end is equivalent to
`move (v1 + v2 + v3)`

We want an optimization: `move (v1 + v2)` is way cheaper then `move v1 . move v2`.

The question: as far I know, that is where Applicative comes handy?
How to implement it in proper Haskell?

I came up with the following: store the info in some container of the form

```
data Move a = Move {data :: a, offset :: Vector}
```

and have a separate function

```
transform :: Movable a => Move a -> a
```

This way we can implement

```
instance Applicative (Move a)
```

But it seems ugly to me. Is there a better way?
Can it be turned into Monad (just to use flexible standard library)

UPD: What I need is:
If I have a Movable object `x`, and I transform it

```
y = move v1 $ move v2 $ move v3 $ x
```

than Haskell must internally make it into

```
y = move (v1 + v2 + v3) x
```

only when I evaluate `y`.

Comment: "Now, say we have a series of computations roughly equivalent to `move v1 . move v2 . move v3` – why though? That seems a rather contrived scenario. In practice you'd more typically have a sequence of different transformations. A step in between like "remove all vertices with negative x-coordinately" would not commute with the movements. That said: there is certainly precetend in computer graphics to grouping objects together with a global transformation. It's usually done to facilitate making duplicates of an object that can be edited together, but that's not a concern when writing code.

Comment: BTW the proper class to use is [vector-space](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space).

Comment: You can implement rewrite rules for optimization, although it is not always clear if these will be applied, since the pattern should be quite specific.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I simplified the question, so it only asks about the language, not internal implementation. What I do have, is affine transformations (they commute of course) of 2d points (or group of points, say polygons). Internally, it uses [Linear.V2](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) type. And yes, it is made for game-dev, so optimization of series of computations which we don't know at the start is rather important.

Comment: @Andrey ...question still looks the same though?

Comment: BTW, `Move` is a monad, since it's the same as `Writer m` with `m = Vector` being the underlying monoid. (I'm not sure this is a sensible approach, though)

Comment: @leftaroundabout, @chi as far as I understand ``Writer`` monad does what I need, but it lacks an ``apply`` function. It will simply return a pair of final transformation and object. I mean, it's not bad, but I want a *user-friendly* interface to my lib, compatible with standard library (if it is possible of course). So using ``Writer`` is fine, but it seems I can write my own Writer-like type and call it ``Move``. It still will lack a good interface :(
I want some walk-around against classical ``Endo`` . Maybe ``Ap`` wrapper will work somehow? Check UPD as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess laziness can help.

```
-- You may want offset :: !Vector, base :: !a.
-- But you definitely don't want result :: !a.
data Moved a = Moved { offset :: Vector, base :: a, result :: a }

-- smart constructor; not really needed, strictly speaking
moved :: Movable a => Vector -> a -> Moved a
moved o b = Moved o b (move o b)

instance Movable a => Movable (Moved a) where
    move v m = moved (v + offset m) (base m)
```

The first time you access the `result` of a `Moved` object, it will be computed, but further accesses will use the previously computed result. Intermediate `result`s will be thrown away without incurring the cost of their `move`s.

This is very similar to your `Move` type, except that your `transform` would recompute its `result` each time it was called. That may not be desirable, especially if there is the opportunity for shared computation; e.g. one could write

```
unmoved :: a -> Moved a
unmoved a = Moved zero a a

rebase :: Movable a => Moved a -> Moved a
rebase = unmoved . result
```

to make a new base object that has accumulated the motions so far; branching off from this object then accumulates a smaller sum in each branch.